# Classes of Probes in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

Throughout the various series, we see many classes of probes launched, What do the various classes do? I would think a class 1 probe would be the least advanced whereas a class 4 would be one of the more advanced probes.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Probe

Comment: [Starfleet Probe Classes](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Probe#Starfleet_probe_classes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best source is the [Star Trek TNG: Technical Manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) which details the nine classes of probes.

The manual is at least semi-canonical, being authorised by Roddenberry and written by people involved with the show.

---

[image]

Comment: Posting a link to an entire ebook is a no-no. Be selective and post just the page :-)

Comment: @Valorum - wouldn't posting the pages be violating copyright?

Comment: @Tim - No. It would come under the heading of 'fair usage' whereas posting a link to a warez site where you can download the book illegally is clearly well beyond fair use.

Comment: @Valorum - makes sense.  It's easy enough to find anyway :-)

Comment: @Tim - See edit.

Comment: So, what do the various classes do?

Comment: Class 9 probes have also been used to carry plot in the form of attractive human-Klingon hybrids.